# Handling concavity in ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, regions

I have imported some CFD results (in csv format) into Mathematica to do some further processing of the data.

One of my 2D geometries is,

[image]

Now, when I try to do the contour plot, I get the following:

[image]

Why is contour plot filling those areas above and below the narrow section with purplish color. Those regions are not even within my X and Y coordinates (see the image for geometry above)?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Also cross-posted [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1839609?p_p_auth=m6MOHYLO).

Comment: I suspect the issue is due to the concave nature of your shape. Finding concave boundaries is much trickier than finding convex shapes. If you could find the boundary of your shape as a region, you might be able to use the `RegionFunction` argument of `ContourPlot` to clip it to the region of interest only.

Comment: The `ListPlot` shows an uneven density of points from which the features emerge.  The `ListContourPlot` has a `z` value that is not necessarily associated with the density of the points.  Without being able to see your data, it's certainly plausible that the two figures should not look similar (other than maybe having the same outer boundary).  What can you show to counter that inference?

Comment: @JimB The ListPlot is showing a csv file containing x and y coordinates only. Then I have another csv file which contains the same x and y cooridinates as the first and second column and a velocity as the third column. So ListContourPlot is used to show the velocity contour. I am not sure if I answered your question correclty. Please let me know.

Comment: @MassDefect Unfortunately the shape is random and I cannot specify it mathematically.

Comment: Can you provide some data for us to work with? That would potentially help. I remember seeing some stuff about concave `ContourPlots` a while back. Alternatively, you can first create a `ListContourPlot` to give you the outer shape, use that to build a `RegionMemberFunction` (it can operate on polygons) and then use _that_ to apply the `RegionFunction` to this `ListDensityPlot`

Comment: @b3m2a1 I can give you the csv file, if that helps. But, I don't know where to upload it. Because I know file attachment is not possible here.

Comment: @MuhamadMohaqeq people use PasteBin, often. Alternately you can share it through the Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks. Will do it first thing tomorrow in the morning when I get to my desk. I don't have my data at home. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you did answer my concern.  I mistakenly assumed your issue was about the difference in the "patterns" observed in the two figures rather than the first figure simply demonstrating the region for which you wanted a dense contour plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an approach you could try, making use of `ListContourPlot` to build a `RegionMemberFunction`:

First I'll make some sample data. This should just be replaced by your actual stuff:

```
cutout = Region@Disk[{-2, 3}, 3];
concaveShape = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 3], cutout];
distFunc = RegionDistance[cutout];
data = Flatten[
   Table[r*{Cos[q], Sin[q]}, {q, 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}, {r, .001, 3, .1}], 1];
data = Pick[data, RegionMember[cutout][data], False];
function = (distFunc@data);
surf = Join[data, ArrayReshape[function, {Length@function, 1}], 2];
```

We can see the [`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) has an issue:

```
concaveShape // RegionPlot
```

[image]

```
ListDensityPlot[surf, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now here's the approach I'd advocate. First make `ListContourPlot` of your data to recover the shape of the `cutout`:

```
regions = ListContourPlot[surf, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Contours -> Subdivide[0, .1, 5]]
```

[image]

Now, we'll use some post-processing to get all of the polygons in that plot. Then we'll find only the purple ones (i.e. those in the cutout). Then we'll take the [`RegionDifference`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference.html) of the [`RegionUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) of all of them and the `RegionUnion` of just the cutout:

```
poly =
  With[{points = regions[[1, 1]]},
   Association@
    Cases[
     regions[[1, 2]], 
     {
       ___,
       c_?ColorQ,
       ___,
       g : _GraphicsGroup | _Polygon
       } :> (c -> (g /. i_Integer :> points[[i]])), 
     Infinity
     ]
   ];

fullRegion =
  RegionUnion@Cases[Values[poly], p_Polygon :> Region[p], Infinity];

cutoutPolygons =
  With[{test = ColorData["Rainbow"][0]},
   KeySelect[poly, ColorDistance[#, test] < .1 &]
   ];

cutoutRegion =
  RegionUnion@Cases[Values[cutoutPolygons], p_Polygon :> Region[p], Infinity];

diff = RegionDifference[fullRegion, cutoutRegion]
```

[image]

Finally we can use [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) to get a new [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) to use in `ListDensityPlot`:

```
rf = RegionMember[diff];
ListDensityPlot[
 surf, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All,
 RegionFunction -> (rf[{#, #2}] &)
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the time you spent on this. I honestly did not think it would be such a difficult thing to do.

Comment: My sense is that it's a non-trivial problem. There might be a better approach, but if there is I don't know it

Comment: Here is a cross-post from Mathematica forum, which contains my csv file. [https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1839609?p_p_auth=m6MOHYLO]

Comment: @MuhamadMohaqeq would be good to mention in the question body that you cross-posted on Wolfram Community

Comment: Just did it. Thanks

Comment: Since you are effectively using the z-values to get the cutout, shouldn't you be able to just use `ListDensityPlot[surf, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> {0.1, All}]`?

Comment: @LukasLang in this simplified case, yes, in other cases the relevant Z value might not be zero and might in fact be in the middle of the range of interest.

Comment: Good point - but I guess in those cases you could just use `RegionFunction -> (!zmin < #3 < zmax&)` or similar, without the need to extract the region. (Please don't take this as criticism of your solution - in fact, the way you extract the region from the plot is really nice :) )

Comment: @LukasLang I didn’t even think of that, but I think that might be a better solution for this problem than mine. You should post it. I’m sure everyone would appreciate seeing that this doesn’t need to be as hard as I made it.

Comment: @MuhamadMohaqeq see Lukas’s solution. It’s much, much simpler if the data you have can be excluded based off of a value cutoff.

Comment: @LukasLang and b3m2a1 Thanks to both of you for your great help.

Comment: @b3m2a1 , Lucas Lang, Since data is available now, why don't you solve actual  problem with your methods?

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that I often encounter and am working on a solution.  In the meantime, a simple hack that I’ve found useful is to draw a polygon with a hole on top of the contour plot.  If you define the hole such that it corresponds to the boundary of the area within which you want the contours To be shown then the contours that lie outside the hole will be blanked out by the overlying polygon. The main hassle with this approach is in defining the hole geometry, especially if it’s highly irregular.  There’s a function in the function repository that aims to semi-automatically define non-convex hulls for irregularly spaced points. This function generally works ok, but not for all cases so some manual intervention may still be necessary.

Here's an example...

(1) Generate some {x,y,z} data.

```
xyz = Table[{x, y, x*y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

(2) Plot the data.

```
cplot=ListContourPlot[xyz]
```

[image]

(3) Define polygon with a hole and plot it.

```
hole = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Gray, Thickness[Tiny]}], FaceForm[White], Polygon[{{-1, -1}, {11, -1}, {11, 11}, {-1, 11}} -> {{1, 1}, {5, 
   5}, {9, 1}, {5, 9}}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

(4) Now show the holed polygon on top of the contour plot.

```
Show[cplot, hole]
```

[image]

(5) If you wanted to, you could also play some tunes with FaceForm Opacity to feintly show the blanked-out contours, e.g.

```
Show[ListContourPlot[xyz],Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Gray, Thickness[Tiny]}], FaceForm[{White, Opacity[0.8]}],Polygon[{{-1, -1}, {11, -1}, {11, 11}, {-1, 11}} -> {{1, 1}, {5,5}, {9, 1}, {5, 9}}] // Rotate[#, 270 \[Degree]] &}]]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you add a link to the function repo page? That's potentially very useful function. Also would it be possible to provide some example code to detail your proposed method?

Comment: I’m not at my computer today, so can’t access any example code.  But here’s the link to Jon McLoon’s function - https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonConvexHullMesh.  And, for plotting polygons with holes see the documentation pages at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html.  Just draw the holed polygon on top of your contour plot and hey presto.  The contours are still there, but shouldn’t be visible because they are blanked-out by the overlying polygon.

Comment: (when you get the chance) it’d be much more helpful if you could actually add some code and examples to the post. More useful for posterity, you know?

Comment: Agreed, will provide an example when I have a mo.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution based on @lan's idea.

Let xyz 1st, 2nd and 6th column of data.

Let's plot it in 2D and 3D.

```
  {ListPlot[Most /@ xyz, Frame -> True, Axes -> False], ListPointPlot3D[xyz]}
```

[image]

Let's extract first layer of point in 3D. 218 is found by try and error.

```
pts = Most /@ TakeSmallestBy[xyz, Last, 218];
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

These points are not ordered.

```
ListLinePlot[pts]
```

[image]

Let's order them counterclockwise.

```
q1 = ReverseSortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &], ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];
q2 = ReverseSortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &], ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];
q3 = SortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] < 0 &], ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];
q4 = SortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] < 0 &], ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];

ListLinePlot[Join[q1, q2, q3, q4, {First@q1}]]
```

[image]

Now we can use these points as a mask. I chose {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}} as frame coordinates.

```
        mask = Join[q1, q2, q3,  q4, {First@q1}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}];
        hole = Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[{Gray, Thickness[Tiny]}], 
        Polygon[mask]}];
```

[image]

Replace `EdgeForm[{Gray, Thickness[Tiny]}]` with `EdgeForm[ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[5] // First]`

And all together, it gives

```
   pts = Most /@ TakeSmallestBy[xyz, Last, 218];
q1 = ReverseSortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &], 
   ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];
q2 = ReverseSortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &], 
   ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];
q3 = SortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] < 0 &], ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];
q4 = SortBy[Select[pts, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] < 0 &], ArcTan[#2/#1 &]];
mask = Join[q1, q2, q3, 
   q4, {First@q1}, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}];
hole = Graphics[{FaceForm[White], 
    EdgeForm[ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[5] // First], 
    Polygon[mask]}];
Show[ListDensityPlot[xyz, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600], hole]
```

[image]

Alternatively we can use `FindCurvePath` to sort the points (Or `FindShortestTour[pts]` will also work, i.e., `orderedPts =pts[[Last@FindShortestTour[pts]]]`).

```
curve = First@FindCurvePath[pts];
orderedPts = pts[[curve]];
ListLinePlot[orderedPts]
```

[image]

```
mask = Join[orderedPts, {{-0.005, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-0.005, 1}}];
hole = Graphics[{FaceForm[White], 
    EdgeForm[ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[5] // First], 
    Polygon[mask]}];
Show[ListDensityPlot[xyz, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600], hole]
```

> Same picture

Comment: you can use `pts` with  [`ListCurvePathPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html) : `Show[ListCurvePathPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red],  ListPlot[xyz[[All, ;; 2]]], Axes -> False]`

Comment: Good point, but ordering is necessary for `Polygon`, no?

Comment: But we can use FindCurvePath[pts] :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on a similar approach as shown by [@b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211148/36508): We cut out regions with a certain range of $z$ values by using [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) or [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html):

Generate a example data set (taken from @b3m2a1's answer):

```
cutout = Region@Disk[{-2, 3}, 3];
concaveShape = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 3], cutout];
distFunc = RegionDistance[cutout];
data = Flatten[
   Table[r*{Cos[q], Sin[q]}, {q, 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}, {r, .001, 3, .1}], 
   1];
data = Pick[data, RegionMember[cutout][data], False];
function = (distFunc@data);
surf = Join[data, ArrayReshape[function, {Length@function, 1}], 2];
```

Do the actual plotting for three different settings: (default, using `PlotRange` and using `RegionFunction`)

```
ListDensityPlot[surf, #] & /@ {
  {}, (* default behaviour, fills the hole *)
  PlotRange -> {0.07, All}, (* use PlotRange to limit the range of values *)
  RegionFunction -> (#3 > 0.07 &) (* use RegionFunction to limit the range *)
}
```

[image]

The first image shows how the plot looks like without any tweaking, so that a convex region is generated. The second example shows how `PlotRange` can be used to limit the range of $z$ values plotted. In more flexibility is needed (e.g. if you want to cut values in an interval), `RegionFunction` can be used: The function is called with $x,y,z$, where $x,y$ are the coordinates of the point and $z$ is the value at that point. To cut out values between 0.2 and 0.5 for example, we'd use

```
ListDensityPlot[surf, RegionFunction -> (! 0.2 <= #3 <= 0.5 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer. It’s simple and will always work for this type of problem. Mathematica does a constant fill when it fills in concavities so there should almost always be a way to describe that with `RegionFunction`.