# Boundaries problem with listdensityplot

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-element-method, plotting

I have to following list to plot (from FEM software) {coord xi, coord yi, speed (norm of) vi} :

```
data = {{9.93371`, 3.60179`, 0.`}, {10.05561`, 3.4799`, 
0.`}, {10.23147`, 3.33651`, 0.49062`}, {10.42954`, 3.10596`, 
0.`}, {10.54697`, 2.98853`, 0.`}, {10.70487`, 3.05962`, 
1.10058`}, {10.93688`, 3.22932`, 1.1813`}, {11.06328`, 3.30958`, 
1.22172`}, {11.18162`, 3.40451`, 1.26253`}, {11.27948`, 3.52455`, 
1.30506`}, {11.36744`, 3.64406`, 1.34518`}, {11.42741`, 3.79263`, 
1.38723`}, {11.46428`, 3.94252`, 1.4262`}, {11.44661`, 4.09893`, 
1.45909`}, {11.39439`, 4.26148`, 1.48745`}, {11.30213`, 4.4117`, 
1.47135`}, {11.17947`, 4.54065`, 1.43523`}, {11.03999`, 4.64212`, 
1.40232`}, {10.89399`, 4.72189`, 1.37388`}, {10.75874`, 4.78219`, 
1.36481`}, {10.62579`, 4.83383`, 1.37037`}, {10.46383`, 4.86916`, 
1.40609`}, {10.2824`, 4.91596`, 1.45279`}, {10.08402`, 4.98567`, 
1.51373`}, {9.97027`, 5.0372`, 1.53897`}, {9.85791`, 5.09069`, 
1.56094`}, {9.73983`, 5.16493`, 1.55862`}, {9.61517`, 5.23915`, 
1.55036`}, {9.4849`, 5.3277`, 1.52584`}, {9.35216`, 5.42282`, 
1.4855`}, {9.2175`, 5.52556`, 1.42655`}, {9.0805`, 5.63398`, 
1.36423`}, {8.94924`, 5.74061`, 1.3045`}, {8.8261`, 5.84396`, 
1.2555`}, {8.607`, 6.03119`, 1.17121`}, {8.49295`, 6.13266`, 
1.13611`}, {8.38028`, 6.23363`, 1.09729`}, {8.23308`, 6.3666`, 
1.04648`}, {8.08936`, 6.501`, 1.01091`}, {8.02755`, 5.50795`, 
0.`}, {8.11056`, 5.42495`, 0.`}, {8.24833`, 5.28717`, 
0.`}, {8.3861`, 5.1494`, 0.`}, {8.55173`, 4.98377`, 
0.`}, {8.70302`, 4.83248`, 0.`}, {8.8543`, 4.6812`, 
0.`}, {8.94114`, 4.59436`, 0.`}, {9.02798`, 4.50752`, 
0.`}, {9.10874`, 4.42676`, 0.`}, {9.1895`, 4.346`, 
0.`}, {9.35102`, 4.18448`, 0.`}, {9.4755`, 4.06`, 0.`}, {9.52572`,
 4.00979`, 0.`}, {9.63764`, 3.89786`, 0.`}, {9.74957`, 3.78593`, 
0.`}, {9.81181`, 3.72369`, 0.`}, {10.65765`, 3.97574`, 
1.32908`}, {10.00578`, 4.37793`, 1.40131`}, {9.53505`, 4.70817`, 
1.28146`}, {9.15971`, 5.01409`, 1.08497`}, {10.46839`, 4.39835`, 
1.42817`}, {8.75244`, 5.36426`, 0.90506`}, {10.27759`, 3.82378`, 
1.16758`}, {11.06109`, 3.96222`, 1.37589`}, {10.62283`, 3.53728`, 
1.21643`}, {8.34333`, 5.74072`, 0.75765`}, {10.84284`, 4.31236`, 
1.41483`}, {9.65123`, 4.37316`, 1.04236`}, {9.88181`, 4.70184`, 
1.50021`}, {9.99744`, 4.0301`, 1.07169`}, {10.94357`, 3.64495`, 
1.28606`}, {8.06924`, 5.89381`, 0.58085`}, {10.38469`, 4.10718`, 
1.35411`}, {10.22755`, 4.60403`, 1.47702`}, {8.47742`, 5.47591`, 
0.63767`}, {9.23557`, 4.72395`, 0.81169`}, {9.03987`, 5.28663`, 
1.18426`}, {8.87957`, 5.05353`, 0.68186`}, {9.45399`, 4.99194`, 
1.39635`}, {11.101`, 4.23019`, 1.43716`}, {8.69549`, 5.61851`, 
1.08879`}, {9.41338`, 4.47832`, 0.77838`}, {9.71174`, 4.88655`, 
1.51276`}, {10.35872`, 3.57028`, 1.00137`}, {9.83076`, 4.20811`, 
1.07981`}, {8.28235`, 6.011`, 0.95185`}, {10.60171`, 3.28777`, 
1.0487`}, {10.69535`, 4.5284`, 1.41986`}, {10.46114`, 4.63371`, 
1.4394`}, {10.16489`, 4.20009`, 1.34803`}, {10.62315`, 4.21398`, 
1.37602`}, {9.03115`, 4.8255`, 0.61088`}, {9.25532`, 5.21875`, 
1.35104`}, {10.52112`, 3.76597`, 1.26416`}, {11.15572`, 3.74677`, 
1.33833`}, {10.83431`, 3.43884`, 1.2213`}, {10.73809`, 3.7255`, 
1.28`}, {10.01814`, 3.80812`, 0.78341`}, {8.68645`, 5.15589`, 
0.52854`}, {8.93649`, 5.47478`, 1.20589`}, {8.61326`, 5.81671`, 
1.1248`}, {10.92365`, 4.11964`, 1.39459`}, {10.17003`, 3.64963`, 
0.7757`}, {11.26498`, 3.9992`, 1.4112`}, {10.25546`, 4.39287`, 
1.43622`}, {10.12423`, 4.78299`, 1.51295`}, {11.01808`, 4.41629`, 
1.43507`}, {8.09804`, 6.09381`, 0.8211`}, {10.85712`, 3.90181`, 
1.33572`}, {9.8269`, 4.49514`, 1.37694`}, {10.21397`, 4.00976`, 
1.26157`}, {8.13599`, 5.69142`, 0.44259`}, {8.28114`, 5.54288`, 
0.45569`}, {9.63743`, 4.17171`, 0.68713`}, {8.4427`, 5.90516`, 
1.03347`}, {9.79984`, 4.01213`, 0.7146`}, {8.04371`, 6.30814`, 
0.93025`}, {8.56928`, 5.30763`, 0.55322`}, {10.33051`, 3.22123`, 
0.24531`}, {10.47457`, 3.42418`, 0.98432`}, {10.4749`, 3.94537`, 
1.29711`}, {8.5118`, 5.65968`, 0.89446`}, {9.7072`, 4.63759`, 
1.37251`}, {10.03228`, 4.57375`, 1.48116`}, {11.10787`, 3.57455`, 
1.2918`}, {9.49888`, 4.2824`, 0.6049`}, {9.96477`, 4.85668`, 
1.53363`}, {9.39081`, 4.82043`, 1.19369`}, {10.87953`, 4.53803`, 
1.41336`}, {10.82087`, 3.14447`, 1.14094`}, {10.9965`, 3.80574`, 
1.33095`}, {9.42185`, 5.1642`, 1.44971`}, {8.87073`, 5.23128`, 
0.90626`}, {9.99766`, 4.19735`, 1.25456`}, {9.57707`, 4.52699`, 
1.12801`}, {9.6225`, 5.03616`, 1.51611`}, {10.32805`, 4.74715`, 
1.46408`}, {8.86744`, 4.84562`, 0.36621`}, {8.72526`, 4.99575`, 
0.35901`}, {9.24558`, 4.54402`, 0.54482`}, {10.68753`, 4.3647`, 
1.41336`}, {9.08253`, 4.6724`, 0.42602`}, {8.40684`, 5.32817`, 
0.34537`}, {10.21653`, 3.49617`, 0.65366`}, {10.35769`, 4.51381`, 
1.44747`}, {8.23971`, 6.16261`, 0.99377`}, {10.75607`, 4.11161`, 
1.37144`}, {8.21281`, 5.82895`, 0.68625`}, {10.31446`, 4.24749`, 
1.39934`}, {10.61898`, 4.67164`, 1.41227`}, {10.46953`, 4.23737`, 
1.38842`}, {9.18317`, 5.3656`, 1.33986`}, {10.53724`, 4.08618`, 
1.35211`}, {10.99565`, 3.4572`, 1.24799`}, {9.38142`, 4.64236`, 
0.94154`}, {10.80259`, 3.58767`, 1.25392`}, {9.29987`, 5.07328`, 
1.28789`}, {9.24527`, 4.88148`, 1.04579`}, {8.46892`, 5.06658`, 
0.`}, {9.27026`, 4.26524`, 0.`}};

a = ListDensityPlot[data]
b = ListPlot[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];
Show[a, b]
```

I chose to make a density plot with it which give me this nice result :

[image]

But it seems to be a problem with the boundaries because if I plot the coordinates over the density plot, the density plot has created an additional undesirable region. The boundaries should pass through the outer blue points.

Any idea how to fix that ?

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: Can you, please, provide the code that you used to make the plot? Without this it is impossible to say what you should do differently, nor determine what problems you are having with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for that, check the update !

Comment: Mathematica calculates a [**convex hull**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your datapoints and then creates a density plot on this region. If you think about it for a second, you see that this is the only logical way, because there is no other _unique_ region defined only by providing the interior points. What you can do is to get the appropriate region (boundary) from your FEM software and then use this to hide the density plot outside this region.

Comment: Let's say you get your boundary points in the appropriate order: `boundary = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}`. Then define a polygon: `poly = Polygon[boundary]` and use `RegionFunction` option inside `ListDensityPlot`: `ListDensityPlot[..., RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[poly, {x, y}]]]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought by looking at similar problems but a priori the perimeter varies for each time step and the file containing the points does not specify this perimeter... If there is a way to determine this contour with mathematica, I am interested.

Comment: See also this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211132/handling-concavity-in-listcontourplot/211267#211267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have mentioned already in the comment, the main problem lies in the fact that there is no unique way to define a *concave* region only by providing the interior points. That is why `ListDensityPlot` automatically creates a convex hull of your points and uses this as a plotting region.

You can, however, create a concave hull. We can use code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109999/75628) and manually tweak the parameter `alpha` to obtain a desired concave region of interest:

```
concaveHullRegion[points_, alpha_] := 
 Module[{dtri, outsideregion, boundaryLineQ}, 
  dtri = Union[
    Sort /@ Flatten[List @@@ MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[points], 1], 1]];
  outsideregion[center_, plist2_] := 
   Module[{empty = True, n = 1, 
     plist3 = SortBy[plist2, Norm[# - center] &]}, 
    Norm[plist3[[1]] - center] > alpha];
  boundaryLineQ[plist_, {id1_, id2_}] := 
   Module[{p1 = plist[[id1]], p2 = plist[[id2]], center1, center2, 
     lhalf}, lhalf = Norm[p2 - p1]/2;
    If[lhalf > alpha, False, 
     center1 = (p2 + p1)/2 + 
       Sqrt[(alpha/lhalf)^2 - 1] {{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . ((p2 - p1)/2);
     center2 = (p2 + p1)/2 + 
       Sqrt[(alpha/lhalf)^2 - 1] {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}} . ((p2 - p1)/2);
     Xor @@ (outsideregion[#, 
          Delete[plist, {{id1}, {id2}}]] & /@ {center1, center2})]];
  BoundaryMeshRegion[points, 
   Line@Select[dtri, boundaryLineQ[points, #] &]]]


region = concaveHullRegion[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], .2];
regionMem = RegionMember[region];
a = ListDensityPlot[data, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},  regionMem[{x, y}]], 
   MaxPlotPoints -> 50];
b = ListPlot[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];
Show[a, b]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot with RegionFunction]

**Important note**: For this particular case, you have to include a `MaxPlotPoints` option, otherwise it does not obey the provided `RegionFunction` option. This seems to me as some kind of a weird bug, because it does work properly for other concave regions.

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you !

Comment: Very nice! When reading OP's question, my first thought was 'you need the concave hull not the convex hull!', then scrolled down to find your answer.  It would be worthwhile I think to wrap this up into a function, like `ConvexListDensityPlot` or `AlphaShapeListDensityPlot`, and put it in the [function repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/).  It could take `alpha` as a parameter.

Comment: Good idea! I haven't yet submitted any functions to the function repository (but have been very eager to do it once!). I will prepare the document and find a way to mention you as the proper author of the code :-) @JasonB.

Comment: I just made one implementation, I am far from a geometry expert. I did some searching and there is already a resource function for the [non-convex hull](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonConvexHullMesh), so in your code here you could simply write `region = ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"][data[[All, ;; 2]], .4]`.  Making a version of `ListDensityPlot` that uses it would really useful I think.